# Unable to connect to mongodb using URL using monstache

Tags: mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, monstache

I've been trying to synchronize my mongodb with elastic for two days and I'm going crazy.
After many attempts and changes in my dockerfile and in my docker-compose I get this error, but the container with mongodb is up and running.

```
monstache        | ERROR 2018/07/27 17:59:07 Unable to connect to mongodb using URL 'mongodb:27018': no reachable servers
monstache        | panic: Unable to connect to mongodb using URL 'mongodb:27018': no reachable servers
monstache        | 
monstache        | goroutine 1 [running]:
monstache        | log.(*Logger).Panicf(0xc420020c30, 0xd4fc15, 0x2d, 0xc42006fc18, 0x2, 0x2)
monstache        |  /usr/local/go/src/log/log.go:219 +0xdb
monstache        | main.main()
monstache        |  /home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/rwynn/monstache/monstache.go:2400 +0x320
monstache exited with code 2
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM golang
ADD build-4.4.0/linux-amd64/monstache /go/bin/monstache
ENTRYPOINT ["monstache", "-mongo-url='mongodb:27018'", "-elasticsearch-url=elasticsearch:9200"]
```

And this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always 
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodb:/usr/share/mongodb/data
    ports:
      - 27018:27017

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    container_name: elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./data/elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  monstache:
    build: ./monstache/
    restart: always
    container_name: monstache
    links:
      - elasticsearch
      - mongodb
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, can you update the docker-compose file here? thanks in advance.

Comment: I upgrade it with the solution that I use. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, we desist to use monstache, and we use [mongo-connector](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector) in a python dockerfile to share the data from mongodb to elasticsearch.

```
FROM python:3.4.3

RUN pip install 'mongo-connector[elastic5]' && \
  pip install 'elastic2-doc-manager[elastic5]'
```

I hope this can help to someone.

Comment: mongo-connector is outdated

Answer (score 0):

You have to change 'mongo-url' to `-mongo-url='mongodb:27017'`, because all your containers are running in docker network and mongodb is available there on port `27017` since this is exposed port.

And the below block in compose file will also make mongodb available on your host network at port `27018` but that is accessible via your browser in your local machine env, not in docker network.

`ports:
      - 27018:27017`

This compose file should also work without links.

`version: '3.3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always 
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodb:/usr/share/mongodb/data
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    container_name: elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./data/elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  monstache:
    build: ./monstache/
    restart: always
    container_name: monstache`